# SSMS - Can I create a default layout?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

Using SSMS 11 to connect to a SQL Server 2012 instance.

1. When I first load up SSMS and log-in, is it possible to have specific nodes in the object explorer expand? I always expand the tables node in a few of the databases that I am constantly accessing, along with the SQL Agent Jobs node.
2. Whenever I add a new table via T-SQL, I refresh the cache with CTRL+SHIFT+R, but I also want to refresh the object explorer tables node without having to use my mouse to right click on "Tables" and hit refresh. In the object explorer, is there a shortcut key to refresh the node you're currently working in?

These sound like minor things, but they'd dramatically improve workflow since I encounter them regularly every day.

Comment: Chances are slim to none, leaning toward none. You may want to appeal to folks who write dedicated plugins to enhance SSMS, like [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/) and [SSMS Tools Pack](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), or request this kind of functionality (or [contribute yourself](https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/wiki/How-to-Contribute)) to [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017), which seems to be where Microsoft will be investing in client tools for SQL Server going forward.